# min and max value for a row, not column

Tags: mysql, database

In my mysql table on the same row i have a persons name, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5. I want to get the lowest value from values 1-5 and put it in column lowestvalue.

I know how to get minimum and maximum values from a chosen column, as stated in mysql documentation 3.6.1, but i dont know how to get minimum and maximum values from a chosen row. I cant find that in mysql documentation.

Could some one tell me or point me in the right direction. Cheers

Comment: you might need to do an unpivot for this one...

Comment: did u try min(persons name) ? can u show ur query

Comment: =_=|| strange request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT GREATEST(`value1`, `value2`, `value3`, `value4`, `value5`) as `highest`
FROM `tablename` WHERE .....
```

Comment: This works, cheers, that was quick, will accept as answer in 9 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Create another table (name, value), link it with first table by name and use standart min/max functions